# ASP.NET Core 6.0 NESTED BINDINGS

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding, asp.net-core-6.0

I can't get it work with multiple nested lists. Only one nested list populate data.

```
public class PriceOffer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidUntilDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    // Relationship
    public ICollection<Window> Windows { get; set; }
}

public class Window
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PriceOfferId")]
    public int PriceOfferId { get; set; }

    public PriceOffer PriceOffer { get; set; }

    // Relationship to Additions
    public ICollection<Addition>? Additions { get; set; }

    // Relationship to Services
    public ICollection<Service>? Services { get; set; }
}

public class Addition
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("WindowId")]
    public int WindowId { get; set; }

    public Window Window { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveOffer(PriceOffer offer)
{
        var customer = await _customersService.GetCustomerByIdAsync(offer.CustomerId);

        offer.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;

        if (customer != null)
        {
            offer.Customer = customer;
        }

        foreach (Window window in offer.Windows)
        {
            var color = await _colorsService.GetColorByIdAsync(window.ColorID);
            var glass = await _glassesServices.GetGlassByIdAsync(window.GlassID);
            var system = await _systemsService.GetSystemByIdAsync(window.SystemID);

            window.Color = color;
            window.Glass = glass;
            window.System = system;
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }

        var data = offer;

        return RedirectToAction("CustomerDetails", "Customers", new { id = 1 });
}
```

Windows, Additions, Services are added dynamically by Javascript. But when I submit form I can get only data for PriceOffer model and Window model, nested window lists are always null.

This is my Window view which work without sending data for Addition or Services.

```
@using PriceOfferApp.Models.Settings;
@model List<Window>
@{
    IEnumerable<Color> colors = ViewData["Colors"] as IEnumerable<Color>;
    IEnumerable<WindowSystem> systems = ViewData["Systems"] as IEnumerable<WindowSystem>;
    IEnumerable<Glass> glasses = ViewData["Glasses"] as IEnumerable<Glass>;
}

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
<input asp-for="@Model[i].Width"/>
<input asp-for="@Model[i].Height"/>
...
}
```

And addition view which does not sending any data to controller:

```
@model List<Addition>

@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <input asp-for="@Model[i].Name"/>
    <input asp-for="@Model[i].Price"/>
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why Addition and Services are not sending also as List to the Controller same as Windows?

Updated for additional codes

This is controller for getting main view

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> CreateOffer(int id)
 {
   var customer = await _customersService.GetCustomerByIdAsync(id);

   if (customer == null)
   {
     Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
     return View("~/Views/Error/404.cshtml");
   }

   PriceOffer priceOffer = new PriceOffer
   {
     Customer = customer,
     CustomerId = customer.Id,
     Windows = new List<Window> { new Window { Id = 1, Additions = new List<Addition> { new Addition { Id = 1 } }, Services = new List<Service> { new Service { Id = 1 } } } },
            };

     ViewData["Colors"] = await _colorsService.GetColors();
     ViewData["Systems"] = await _systemsService.GetSystems();
     ViewData["Glasses"] = await _glassesServices.GetGlasses();

     return View(priceOffer);
   }
```

And this is main view to which are inserted as many as user want partial view for Windows, Addition and Services via jQuery.

```
@model PriceOffer
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "New price offer";
}
<div class="flex items-center mt-8">
    <h2 class="mr-auto text-lg font-medium">New price offer</h2>
</div>
<form asp-action="SaveOffer" method="post">
    <input hidden asp-for="CustomerId" value=@Model.CustomerId />
    <div class="grid grid-cols-11 pb-20 mt-5 gap-x-6">
        <!-- Left Side -->
        <div class="col-span-11 2xl:col-span-9">
            <ul id="sort-windows-all">
                <partial name="~/Views/PriceOffers/_NewWindow.cshtml" for="Windows" />
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Right Side-->
        <div class="hidden col-span-2 2xl:block">
            <div class="sticky top-0 pt-10">
                <!-- Add New Window -->
                <button id="add-new-window" type="button">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="stroke-1.5 w-4 h-4 mr-2">
                        <line x1="12" y1="5" x2="12" y2="19"></line>
                        <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12"></line>
                    </svg>
                    Add window
                </button>
                <!-- Save Offer -->
                <button id="save-offer" type="submit">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="stroke-1.5 w-4 h-4 mr-2">
                        <path d="M19 21H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V5a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h11l5 5v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2z"></path>
                        <polyline points="17 21 17 13 7 13 7 21"></polyline>
                        <polyline points="7 3 7 8 15 8"></polyline>
                    </svg>
                    Save offer
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you post more codes? I didn't see the action " customerdetails" and the entry point of return view().

Comment: @mxmissile - I know but I did not finish that code because post request does not work as expected so Im not calling services API to save within DB.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by custom name for inputs and not using asp-for.

```
Windows[@(ViewData["windowID"])].Additions[@(i)].Price
```

And than in JavaScript when I'm adding or removing views programmatically I'm replacing values in square bracket.

And then all data are pushed to controller.